# Intuition for this observation//how restrictive is this assumption?

Tags: probability, distributions

For many common continuous unimodal distribution function $F$ with density $F'$, I find that the derivative (wrt $x$) of

$$(1)\quad \frac{F'(x)}{F''(x)}$$

i.e.

$$\frac {d}{dx}\left(\frac{F'(x)}{F''(x)}\right)$$

is positive (this is the case for the Weibull, normal, log-normal, exponential, gamma and probably others as well).

In one theorem I am working on, I need that the derivative of (1) is positive and $F$ unimodal and continuous. I am wondering how restrictive it is to assume that the derivative of (1) is positive for unimodal continuous distributions $F$.

## Edit:

Maybe the set of all distributions for which the derivative of (1) is positive has a name, or has been studied. I would like to know those things.

Comment: In what sense do you want to analyze or quantify "restrictive"? Of course this criterion excludes some distributions, because not all unimodal ones are log convex.

Comment: @whuber: it is not clear to me how this relates to [log-convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function). Could you make your comment more explicit?

Comment: Let $f(x)=F^\prime(x)$. Since 

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{F^\prime(x)}{F^{\prime\prime}(x)} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(1/\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}\right)= \frac{d}{dx}\left(1/\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x))\right)=-\frac{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log(x)}{{(\cdots)}^2},$$ the positivity of the left hand side assures the negativity of the second derivative of $\log(f)$. A standard Calculus theorem asserts $\log(f)$ is convex (on an open set) provided its second derivative is everywhere positive. That's what "log-convex" means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The OP really seeks the distributions with log-*concave* density functions** -the quotient he differentiates is the *reciprocal* of the one we examine in order to determine the log-concavity or log-convexity of a function.

Specifically:
For $f$ to be log-concave, it means that $\ln f$ is concave, for which we require that

$$\frac {d^2}{dx^2} \ln f \leq 0 \implies \frac {d}{dx}\left (\frac {f'}{f}\right) \leq 0 \implies f''\cdot f-(f')^2 \leq 0$$

From his part, the OP wants

$$\frac {d}{dx} \left (\frac {F'}{F''}\right) \geq 0 \implies \frac {d}{dx} \left (\frac {f}{f'}\right) \geq 0 \implies (f')^2 - f\cdot f'' \geq 0 $$

and upon re-arranging, the OP wants

$$ f\cdot f'' - (f')^2 \leq 0$$

which is the condition for *log-concavity*, *not* log-convexity.
It is the expression of the condition through the use of the reciprocal quotient that may cause some confusion.

A good free resource on some of the "named" distributions that have log-concave densities is

[Mark Bagnoli and Ted Bergstrom. "Log-concave Probability and its Applications" 2004](http://works.bepress.com/ted_bergstrom/98/)

It focuses on log-concavity but it also contains results on log-convexity. We see that the OP's assertion that "Weibull, normal, log-normal, exponential, gamma" have log-concave densities is not fully correct: for example, the normal and the exponential distribution do have log-concave densities, while Weibull and gamma have also log-concave densities for some of their incarnations, while for others they have log-convex densities. The log-normal has a density that is neither log-concave, nor log-convex.

Another resource that examines log-concavity and log-convexity more abstractly and rigorously is

[An, M. Y. (1998). Logconcavity versus logconvexity: a complete characterization. Journal of Economic theory, 80(2), 350-369.](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mark_An/publication/4977452_Logconcavity_versus_Logconvexity_A_Complete_Characterization/links/540a343c0cf2d8daaabfa20c.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the link Alecos! This is *exactly* what I want to read now!

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=F^\prime(x)$. Since

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{F^\prime(x)}{F^{\prime\prime}(x)} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(1/\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}\right)= \frac{d}{dx}\left(1/\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x))\right)=-\frac{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log(x)}{{(\cdots)}^2},$$ the positivity of the left hand side assures the negativity of the second derivative of $\log(f)$. A standard Calculus theorem asserts $\log(f)$ is concave (on an open set) provided its second derivative is everywhere negative. That's what ["log-concave"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function) means.

An important technical condition is that the domain of the function be convex. Convex sets of real numbers are intervals, potentially infinite ones.  The "support" of a continuous density function $f$ is the closure of the set of numbers where it is nonzero. By extension, we may also call that set the support of the distribution function $F$.

**Your functions therefore are all the distribution functions of interval support whose density functions are second-differentiable and log-concave.**

---

**Why the technicalities about the support?** To rule out situations where this *local* characterization is not a global one.  For instance, let $X$ be a random variable with density function equal to $2x$ on the interval $(0,1)$ and zero elsewhere.  Consider the distribution function $F$ of an equal mixture of $X$ and $X+2$.  Its density is defined, nonzero, and continuously differentiable in $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ where its log is either $\log(x)$ or $\log(x-2)$.  Both are concave functions--but $F$ should not qualify as a log-concave distribution because $f$ itself is obviously not concave and log-concavity is intended to be even stronger than concaveity.

Couldn't we not bother with this and just require $F$ to be supported on the entire real line?  Sure--but that would rule out interesting and important examples like Gamma distributions.

Comment: @Alecos Thank you, you're right: I got them mixed up.  (The terminology gets reversed in certain situations: for instance, the lower envelope of the graph of a *concave* function--which is what one would naturally look at in a density function-- is a *convex* set.)  I will correct the terminology.

Comment: Yeah, there is this unfortunate "convex set" and "convex function" terminology issue.